# Как добавить директорию в контроль git если находится в другой директории?

Tags: git

Проект который находится под версионный контролем, находится по такому пути:

`/home/projects/project_name/`
но также к этому проекту относятся несколько системных файлов из
`/etc/system/systemd`

каким образом можно добавить эти файлы к проекту, чтобы они отслеживались ?

Инициализировать там гит, и вести два репозитория не хочется, хотелось бы, чтобы все в одном репозитории было.

Comment: Никак. В общем случае вы хотите странного. Обычно в git хранят не сами конфиги, а примеры. А конфиги создаются в процессе выкладки вручную или скриптами. Ну или как простой вариант, в `/etc/...` создаются симлинки на файлы которые лежат у вас репозитории.

Comment: @AlexeyTen симлинки не катят. Архитектура systemd не позволяет работать с символьными ссылками.

Comment: Ну тогда см. пункт первый

Comment: Научиться пакетировать программы для выбранного(ых) дистрибутива(ов) и перестать страдать странным.

Answer (score 0):

1. (не очень хороший вариант) можно создать символические ссылки в нужном вам каталоге (`/etc/systemd/system`) на файлы в вашем хранилище.

   возражение:

   > Архитектура systemd не позволяет работать с символьными ссылками

   не соответствует реальности: отлично работает (по крайней мере в установленной у меня версии 241 программы *systemd*). в этом можно убедиться, просто посмотрев содержимое этого каталога. одни лишь ссылки и ни одного файла:

   ```
   $ find /etc/systemd/system/ -type l | wc -l
   57
   $ find /etc/systemd/system/ -type f | wc -l
   0
   ```
2. (вариант получше) можно держать в хранилище скрипт, корректно обновляющий файлы в  нужном вам каталоге (`/etc/systemd/system`) исходя из содержимого файлов в вашем хранилище. и вручную запускать его при необходимости.
3. (пожалуй самый правильный вариант для описанной ситуации) можно создать пакет для используемого вами пакетного менеджера. исходники пакета можно держать в том же хранилище. обновили файлы пакета — сгенерируйте его новую версию и установите в систему. только держать в нём, как справедливо подсказывает [@Oxyd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/285858/oxyd) в комментарии, стоит симлинки не в каталоге `/etc/systemd/system`, а в более походящем для этого `/lib/systemd/system`.

Comment: Не очень хорошая идея класть в репу содержимое `/etc/systemd/*` Эта ветвь каталогов предназначена для создания/редактирования юнитов системным администратором. Так называемые vendors units в целевую систему должны устанавливаться в `/lib/systemd/*` (`/lib/systemd/system/*` — для системных юнитов и `/lib/systemd/user/*`, для пользовательских).

Comment: @Oxyd, долго размышлял, стоит ли дополнять ответ такими пакетными деталями — это ведь уже совсем за рамками вопроса — и всё-таки решил, что надо. спасибо за напоминание!

Comment: Надо ибо не все любят читать маны, в которых написано как делать правильно.